# Copying "Field Content" amongst different Content Types?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-content-types

In D7, I have two Content Types (A & B). I want to be able to copy the existing content of certain fields in my first content type, (Content Type A), into this second brand new content type, Content Type B.

I made [a short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4o28V_poiM&hd=1) to explain this and help you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Initially from title, i thought you might be able to achieve this using [Node_clone](https://drupal.org/project/node_clone) & [Node_convert](https://drupal.org/project/node_convert) modules but after going through the video it looks like your requirement is little specific which you can achieve using a small custom module.

Proposed Logic:

1. Using jquery, setup `.change()` event on Node reference field.
2. On value change, make an ajax call & get the node data.
3. Update current node fields with the ajax response.

Hope this will help.